# How to use form function like isPost() in user widget of socialengine?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, socialengine

I am trying to move the function of joining and leaving network to member home page. So I created a user widget block called "channel-indicator" to do that but encountered problem in writting the controller.php code. I tried to use &this->getrequest()->isPost() function in Controller but facing error of " Fatal error: Call to a member function isPost() on a non-object in "application/modules/User/widgets/channel-indicator/Controller.php".
I am a beginner for zend framework, can somebody give me some suggestion in that?

below is the part of code I would like to put in to my controller.php

```
$this->view->form = $form = new User_Form_Settings_Network();

if( !$this->getRequest()->isPost() ) {
  return;
}

if( !$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) ) {
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Please create new action(ex.abcAction) and try to set form action(action="/controller/abc")
and try form post in controller action. The widget form action is seting to default page so you are getting the error.